# Get rid of index while outputting multi header pandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
header = [np.array(['location','location','location','location2','location2','location2']), 
np.array(['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','S6'])] 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 6), columns = header ) 
df
```

I want to export my dataframe to an excel sheet ignoring the index. Here is my code which exports my dataframe to excel spreadsheet but with index. when I am using the parameter, index = False, It gives me an error.

```
# output all the consolidated input to an excel sheet
out_file_name = os.path.join(folder_location, "templates", future_template)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_file_name, engine='xlsxwriter')
# Write each dataframe to a different worksheet.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Ratings Inputs')
# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: What error the index False gives you?

Comment: This is the error message I got with index = False "NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented."

Comment: Oh then what happens is that you don't have an updated version of pandas this is a feature implemented in 0.17 if I recall correctly. Just update your pandas.

Answer (score 0):

`DataFrame.to_excel(index=False)` is still unsupported for MultiIndex (as of Pandas 1.3.4, Oct 2021). You will get the error:

`NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.`

You can try some workarounds instead:

1. Write with `index=True`. Then using `openpyxl`, re-open the file, delete the undesired cols/rows, and re-save the file. This is a slow process, so it may not be practical for large dataframes.
2. You can manually write the MultiIndex headers. This won't have merged cells though. See [How to hide the rows index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961010/how-to-hide-the-rows-index/57961084#57961084)